# Can't parse XML with and access nodes as properties

Tags: xml, parsing, powershell

I have the following XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema
-design/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Language="en-US" Id="sample-extension" Version="0.1.0" Publisher="wouterdekortplayground"/>
    <DisplayName>Sample Extension</DisplayName>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">This is the extension file from the contributions guide example on GitHub.  Feel free to add or remove sections as y
ou see fit.</Description>
    <GalleryFlags/>
    <Tags>Sample</Tags>
    <Properties>
      <Property Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Links.Home" Value="https://bit.ly"/>
      <Property Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Links.Getstarted" Value="https://bit.ly"/>
      <Property Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Links.Learn" Value="https://bit.ly"/>
      <Property Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Links.Support" Value="https://bit.ly"/>
      <Property Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Links.Repository" Value="https://bit.ly"/>
      <Property Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Links.Issues" Value="https://bit.ly"/>
      <Property Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Branding.Color" Value="#dcebfc"/>
      <Property Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Branding.Theme" Value="light"/>
    </Properties>
    <Categories>Integrate</Categories>
    <Icon>img/logo.png</Icon>
  </Metadata>
  <Dependencies/>
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"/>
  </Installation>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Icons.Default" d:Source="File" Path="img/logo.png" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="img/logo.png" d:Source="File" Path="img/logo.png" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="css/app.css" d:Source="File" Path="css/app.css" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="css/jasmine.css" d:Source="File" Path="css/jasmine.css" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="scripts/app.d.ts" d:Source="File" Path="scripts/app.d.ts" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="scripts/app.js" d:Source="File" Path="scripts/app.js" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="scripts/app.js.map" d:Source="File" Path="scripts/app.js.map" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="scripts/app.ts" d:Source="File" Path="scripts/app.ts" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="scripts/Deploy.ps1" d:Source="File" Path="scripts/Deploy.ps1" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="scripts/jasmine-html.js" d:Source="File" Path="scripts/jasmine-html.js" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="scripts/jasmine.js" d:Source="File" Path="scripts/jasmine.js" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="scripts/VSS.SDK.js" d:Source="File" Path="scripts/VSS.SDK.js" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="index.html" d:Source="File" Path="index.html" Addressable="true"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Manifest" d:Source="File" Path="extension.vsomanifest" Addressable="true"/>
  </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

I'm trying to modify this XML with PowerShell. I've read the text from a file in a ZIP archive. I then convert it to XML:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $PathToVSIX,
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $Token,       
    [string] $BaseUrl
)

Set-StrictMode -Version 3
$VerbosePreference = "continue" 

$file = Get-ChildItem $PathToVSIX -Filter *.vsix -Recurse |
        % { $_.FullName } | Select -First 1
Write-Verbose "Found VSIX Package $file"

# Load ZipFile (Compression.FileSystem) if necessary
try { $null = [IO.Compression.ZipFile] }
catch { [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem') }

# Open zip file with update mode (Update, Read, Create -- are the options)
try { $fileZip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open( $file, 'Update' ) }
catch { throw "Another process has locked the '$file' file." }

$desiredFile = [System.IO.StreamReader]($fileZip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.FullName -match 'extension.vsixmanifest' }).Open()
$text = $desiredFile.ReadToEnd()
[xml]$xml = $text | ConvertTo-Xml 
$desiredFile.Close()
$desiredFile.Dispose()
```

Everything seems to go OK but somehow I can't acces `PackageManifest` or other nodes.

When I try to access `$xml.PackageManifest` I get an error stating

> The property 'PackageManifest' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell 5.0 (Build 10586  Version 63) 
I've updated the question with some lines that make sure the assembly is loaded. I suppose that's why you got an error. Since it works with a regular Get-Content, I think the problem is that I load a file in a ZIP archive as regular text and then convert to XML.

Comment: yes... that is stupid of me... I get it now. the open method is from the zip files. Stream reader works with paths. If that is returning the text itself I could see an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two issues with your code:

- [`ConvertTo-Xml`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849889.aspx) doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It's for converting objects to an XML representation, not for parsing XML strings into XML objects, so the result isn't what you expect it to be:

  ```
  PS C:\> [xml]$xml = $text | ConvertTo-Xml
  PS C:\> $xml.Save([Console]::Out)
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
  <Objects>
    <Object Type="System.String">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
  &lt;PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schem
  as.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema
  -design/2011"&gt;
    &lt;Metadata&gt;
      &lt;Identity Language="en-US" Id="sample-extension" Version="0.1.0" Publisher="wouterdekortplayground"/&gt;
      &lt;DisplayName&gt;Sample Extension&lt;/DisplayName&gt;
  ...
  ```

  From the documentation (emphasis mine):

  > ## Detailed Description
  >
  > The ConvertTo-Xml cmdlet ***creates an XML-based representation of one or more Microsoft .NET Framework objects.*** To use this cmdlet, pipe one or more objects to the cmdlet, or use the InputObject parameter to specify the object.

  And you don't need it in the first place. Simply casting the XML string to an XML object is enough:

  ```bsh
  [xml]$xml = $text
  ```

  ```
  PS C:\> [xml]$xml = $text
  PS C:\> $xml.Save([Console]::Out)
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
  <PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.
  microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema -design/2011">
    <Metadata>
      <Identity Language="en-US" Id="sample-extension" Version="0.1.0" Publisher="wouterdekortplayground" />
      <DisplayName>Sample Extension</DisplayName>
  ...
  ```
- Your XML data uses namespaces:

  ```xml
  <PackageManifest Version="2.0.0"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
  ```

  so you need a [namespace manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) for selecting the nodes:

  ```bsh
  $nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
  $nsm.AddNamespace('ns', $xml.DocumentElement.xmlns)
  $xml.SelectNodes('//ns:PackageManifest', $nsm)
  ```